# Angular Uncaught Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'kc'

Tags: javascript, angular, mean-stack

I have problem while running my MEAN Stack app use `ng-build --prod` command. My terminal running well, no error occurs. But when I open the browser in localhost:4200, my app didn't show anything. And then the console give me this error :

```
> Uncaught Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'kc'.
    at e.resolve (main.371a82c9fcb51afc1df0.js:1)
    at e.getNgModuleMetadata (main.371a82c9fcb51afc1df0.js:1)
    at e._loadModules (main.371a82c9fcb51afc1df0.js:1)
    at e._compileModuleAndComponents (main.371a82c9fcb51afc1df0.js:1)
    at e.compileModuleAsync (main.371a82c9fcb51afc1df0.js:1)
    at e.compileModuleAsync (main.371a82c9fcb51afc1df0.js:1)
    at e.bootstrapModule (main.371a82c9fcb51afc1df0.js:1)
    at Object.zUnb (main.371a82c9fcb51afc1df0.js:1)
    at p (runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js:1)
    at Object.3 (main.371a82c9fcb51afc1df0.js:1)
```

I don't know why this happen, because when I run it use `ng-build` without `--prod` , my app running well. This is my **main.ts** file :

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import 'hammerjs';
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(() => {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js');
    }
  })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

And below my **app.module.ts** :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Internship Program Tracer';
  constructor(
    private authService : AuthService,
    private router : Router,
  ){
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

UPDATE :
When I compiles my project using **ng serve --prod** there's no vendor.js found :

```
Date: 2018-10-16T22:20:26.127Z
Hash: d2be935ebafc240e254f
Time: 57889ms
chunk {0} runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js (runtime) 1.05 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} styles.ad29f085d4a251cb6386.css (styles) 43.9 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.19a6a3da76674acaee2e.js (polyfills) 59.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} main.9f6403673fe64ddd0b86.js (main) 684 kB [initial] [rendered]
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

But when I compiles **ng serve** vendor.js found :

```
Date: 2018-10-16T22:23:38.817Z
Hash: 91cb9d988bc421669cc9
Time: 23624ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 289 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 224 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 62.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 6.5 MB [initial] [rendered]
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: Do you have any class named kc in your project?

Comment: I don't have any kc class in my project.

Comment: I don't know why but now the 'Kc' changed to be 'Nc'.

Comment: are you sure this is the content of app.module.ts and not of app.component.ts? if it is, then your module definition is missing. strange that it even compiles on ng serve.

Comment: Yes, I don't know why it can compiles with ng serve, but not with --prod flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this if the problem is only with prod build and your application works well on ng serve:

npm cache clean --force

npm install

npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest